# Determine the 19-th, 20-th and 21-st order Maclaurin polynomial?

Tags: taylor-expansion

[image]

The answers tell me that the solution is:

[image]

Firstly, I don't understand the notation "x$\to$". What does this mean?

This is my attempt to find the maclaurin polynomial for x(1-cos2$x^3$):

x(1-cos(2$x^3$)) = x(1-(1-$\frac{(2x^3)^2}{2!} + \frac{(2x^3)^4}{4!} - \frac{(2x^3)^6}{6!}$+...) = x($\frac{2^2x^6}{2!} - \frac{2^4x^{12}}{4!} + \frac{2^6x^{18}}{6!}$+...)

= ($\frac{2^2x^7}{2!} - \frac{2^4x^{13}}{4!} + \frac{2^6x^{19}}{6!}$+...)

=$\frac{2^{n+1}x^{6n+1}}{(2n)!}$

But I must be on the completely wrong track as I don't see how this leads to the correct answer.

Comment: The arrow means that it is a function that *maps* its argument $x$ to the value $x(1-\cos 2x^3)$. That is, it "takes" any real number as parameter, denoted $x$, and "returns" the value $x(1-\cos 2x^3)$. (This arrow is part of the formalism for function; the $\LaTeX$ code for it is \mapsto, which describes rather well its meaning.) In other terms, $x\mapsto x(1-\cos 2x^3)$ has the same meaning as "the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x(1-\cos 2x^3)$ for any $x$."

Comment: The notation $x\mapsto$ means that you have a function that associate each $x$ to $x(1-\cos{2x^3})$.

Comment: Also, your expansion is correct (except for the last equality, where there seems to be missing a sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$), and does match the answer from your answer sheet. Why do you think it is wrong? ($\frac{2^2}{2!} = 2$, $\frac{2^4}{4!} = \frac{2}{3}$, and $\frac{2^6}{6!} = \frac{4}{45}$)

Comment: Ah I see - but wouldn't this be the 1st, 2nd and 3rd order Maclaurin Polynomials (not the 19th, 20th and 21st)?

Comment: The confusion here is in the terms. "$k$-th order polynomial $p_k$" means "expansion up to term $x^k$, and not more". You interpret it as "up to $k$ non-zero coefficients," which is *not* the same (and not what is asked).

Comment: The first (or zeroth, it is a matter of taste) is $0$. The second is $0$. The third is $0$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now :)